# How to show compatibility action bar in MapActivity in android api level 9+?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-actionbar

How to show Action bar in application which is showing maps and use mapActivity. I can not use Sherlock action bar because it should be [SherlockActivity](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/using-an-actionbar-in-your-application-with-actionbarsherlock/) and I have MapsActivity. I have to support it from Api level 9+. From 11+ I have the native action bar implemented and it works well. I have to use maps api ver 1 and can not use in this reales the new version 2 google maps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably have a look at the new Google Play Services. I read they with a new Maps API which lets you use MapFragments. You could probably use these Fragments in an Sherlock based activity.
Another way would be to use a TabHost to host the MapActivity inside an Sherlock based activity. But i don't know how performant that would be.

Comment: I have to use for this realse of my applicatiopn the old maps, I can not use the new google play service in this version. I think tabhost is not the best way to do it